# Addition and Subtraction of a char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to add and/or subtract number to char* in C
this code doesn't work for some reason. using char without pointer works though.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *A;

    *A = 'A';
    *A += 1;

    printf("%c",*A);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what the term for this problem is called so a just create a new one

Comment: The term for the problem is _undefined behavior_. You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions.  You can't ask new questions because you've been question banned by the system for asking poorly received questions (as [you point out in your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35459957/5)) but the answer isn't to deface your questions. The answer is to start to answer other questions and get upvotes; which will cause the system to recognize that you are a valuable contributor.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't allocated  space for the character and the pointer is not initialized, so dereferencing the pointer will result in undefined behavior.

Initialize it beforehand like this:

```
char a;
char* A = &a;
```

or use just a `char` and obtain a pointer to it using `&a`.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behaviour as `A` does not point to anything and you are *dereferencing* it.

Either point it to an automatic variable: `char c; char* A = &c;`, or set it to the return of a `malloc` call.

Note that you *must* initialise the value of the `char` to which you are pointing, otherwise the behaviour of `*A += 1;` will too be undefined. Fortunately you actually do that with your statement `*A = 'A';`.

Answer (score 1):

*key:* *A pointer must be declared and also initialized.*

---

**----  General Syntax  ----**

Declaration:
**data-type *pointer_name;**

Initialization:
**pointer_name = variable_address**

---

***Example:***

```
    char a = 'A' ;
    char *ptr ;        //pointer declaration
    ptr = &a ;         //pointer initialization
```

or

```
    char a = 'A' ;
    char *ptr = &a ;   //initialization and declaration together.
```

---

So your code will look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  char a = 'A';
  char *A = &a;

  *A = 'A';
  *A += 1;

  printf("%c",*A);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Output: **B**

Comment: The `*A = 'A';` seems pretty much redundant to me.